# What is difference between equivalence class testing and input domain partitioning?

Tags: testing

I'm learning software testing now, just wondering what is difference between equivalence class testing and input domain partitioning, seems like both of them about to partition input domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Frankly saing, during my career as software testing engineer I haven't met a lot of mentions about input domain partitions.

But nevertheless this term exists and let's try to take a look is there a difference between equivalence class testing and input domain partitioning?

**Equivalence class technique** divides possible test data for, let's say application module, into partitions of equivalent data. They're "equivalent" because any member of that partition can perfectly represent the other member of that partition, and theoretically you need only one test using one of the partitions' members in order to make testing of that partition enough sufficient. Moreover the partitions should not overlap.

Yes I know, that's a little bit cumbersome, but let's take a look on the example: you have an input field on the web page which accepts all kind of chars but up to 256 of them. It gives you following equivalence partitions (simplified):

- Char types:

  - only letters
  - only numbers
  - only special chars
  - mixed chars (letters + numbers + spec. chars)
- Char quantity:

  - 0
  - >0
  - <256
  - 256

Each of that equivalence partitions has sub-partitions, e.g. "letters":

- Big letters
- Small letters
- Mixed letters

That means that in order to sufficiently test "letters partitions" you have to design test case which will include at least one of those sub-partitions. Let's say it will be "letters -> Big letters": "TEST INPUT STRING". Take a look that here we've also combined our test string with "Char quantity - >0" equivalence partition.

So basicly saying combining sub-partitions of "Char types" and "Char quantities" partitions, you'll be able to design a minimum test set for testing input data of that field.

From the other side **input domain for a program** *contains all the possible inputs to that program* which is farely equal to *equivalence classes of possible inputs of the application module*.

Sometimes the ones who speak about input domain for a program, say also about **regions** which is the same thing as sub-partition of equivalence partitions. Moreover those input domains (and accordingly regions) must not overlap (so must they not within equivalence partition testing).

With all that said I would consider those two terms as ones, that describe the same matter but using different words.

Comment: Though partitions are good but you mentioned only classes for VALID values. For char quantity we can also add classes for INVALID values like : char quantity<0( it can be assumed as empty text box) and char quantity >256.